# In search display controller, search only current files and folder not subfolder and files in iPad

Tags: xcode, nsarray, nsfilemanager, nsenumerator

I am working on a file Manager application, if user search for a keyword then all the files and folders which are available at given path,filename should listed in a table view which have that search keyword. The Search must be same as in finder for specific folder.

Issue is -
When I search any keyword it's display only current folder or files which in table view but I want to display all subfolder's files also.

E.g
    **LocalFolder**

```
         ->>      **folder1**
                     -->f1.txt
                     -->f2.png
                     -->folder11
         ->>      **folder2**
```

In this case, when you search something it display current folder/files like folder1 and folder2. I need to find into subdirectory also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you made the file search, but i assume you use `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` while getting paths from the search directory. Use `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` instead `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath`, it retruns the paths of all of the contained subdirectories.

```
NSArray * contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath: searchPath error:nil]; 
// Now make your search.
```

Look [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) for more information.

Comment: Please give me another solution because I am not getting what exactly does. something is missing which I don't know for searching character from all files and folder.

Comment: What is missing? Is result of `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` is nil? Are you sure `searchPath` is right? Please be more specific.

Comment: Leftbar have localfolder which have allfiles and that display on tableview in right side.Search funn search any word/character then it display files/folder.NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[fileManager subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:strTemp error:nil]]; I am using this. Now, in tableview display all the files and subfolder(e.g folder1,folder1/f1.txt). Is it possible not display all files and folder with subfolder and sub files in tableview? But it should be display when you  search particular file and it should get from any subfolder.Any idea?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if I understood this, but i'll give it a try. If you want to display files&folders in one directory without its subdirectories content, use `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` for that. If you want to search one directory with its subdirectories, use `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` while searching. Beyond that I can't really help without seeing your project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks... Yes, I am using `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` and now, I checked with `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` in function of `getfilesandfolder`. It's amazing. Display path with subfolder and files.                                                       But issue is that when I search any word or character, then containing files and folder are not display(result not found).Using this `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath`  it would be display all files and folder with subpath name.

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

    [marrFiles removeAllObjects];

    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in marrTmp)

  {
        NSString *tempStr = @"";

     if ([tempDict valueForKey:@"Folder"])
        {
            tempStr = [tempDict valueForKey:@"Folder"];
        }else{
            tempStr = [tempDict valueForKey:@"File"];
        }


       if ([tempStr rangeOfString:searchString].location != NSNotFound) {
            [marrFiles addObject:tempDict];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```